# LF353 for 12-0V square wave from arduino

Tags: arduino, operational-amplifier, square

I have built the following circuit with an LF353N op amp and expecting 0-12V outputs from it.
I have built it on a breadboard but the output is always around +12V except the when the (+) input is floating, at that time it is around 6V. What I am doing wrong? Is the LF353 can not work from a single supply?

My project would be to create 1Khz 12V square wave with an arduino thats why I would like to built it.

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: That's certainly not an oscillator circuit.

Comment: The common mode input voltage can be 3V more than the negative supply. Most likely the circuit can't compare 0V input with 2.5V reference. What would be the device that needs to be driven with 12V square wave, perhaps there is another way of level shifting 5V 1kHz square wave to 12V, if you just tell for what the 12V 1kHz square wave is for.

Comment: Thank you! @Justme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Common-mode input voltage range is down to 4V with a 0/12V supply according to the [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lf353.pdf?ts=1626094858807&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FLF353).

You are operating one input at 0V/5V and the other at 2.5V. Only one of those voltages is within the common mode voltage range. The output won't swing all the way to 0V or +12 either (more like 1.5V/10.5V typically with a 10K load), but set that aside for now.

[image]

**It would be easiest to use a different op-amp** - one that is either rail-to-rail input or "single supply". You may also want rail-to-rail output.

Depending on the internal workings of the op-amp you might be able to get away with changing the bias from +2.5V to about +4.6V and allowing the input to go outside the CM voltage range. If that doesn't work, you can add two more resistors and change the 0/5V to 4.2V/5V and leave the bias at +4.6V, which will work with your current op-amp (though the output voltage swing won't be 0/12V)

Comment: Thank you @Spehro Pefhany! It helped a lot. I have read about this Input Common-Mode Voltage but not fully clear to me. This value specifies the difference between the two inputs, the average or the absolute values? I have read that: "Common mode voltage range is defined as the average of the two inputs. It describes the range of input that can be used for normal linear operation. When you exceed the common mode range the output becomes nonlinear." In my case as I am understanding 12V/0V supply the limits are 8V to 4V. So both inputs should be in this range or the delta  or the average?

Comment: Both inputs should be in the range 4 to 8V at all times to meet the worst case datasheet requirements. In your particular application (as a comparator) it *may* work with just one input always within that range, but it is not guaranteed that I can see.

Comment: Thank again. I will give a try!